# SQL query to select out of 3 options and from other table, based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

I need an SQL query for a somewhat complex SELECT. Assuming the following tables:

```
Table 1:                                Table 2:  
name   | email      | callingcardid     id | name   | email
-------|------------|--------------     ---|--------|----------------
first  | e@mail.com | null              1  | second | second@mail.com 
second |            | 1
third  |            | null
```

Output should be:

```
name   | email
-------|-----------
first  | e@mail.com
second | second@mail.com
third  | -
```

The query should be something like

```
SELECT table1.name, COALESCE(NULLIF(table1.email, ''),  
CASE WHEN table1.callingcardid != NULL  
THEN (SELECT table2.email WHERE id = table1.callingcardid) ELSE '-' END) "email"
```

The syntax is obviously wrong, since I can't get it to work. There are a couple of other columns with joins from other tables, but otherwise it works. The `CASE` clause is the problem maker.

Database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (or 2012).

Comment: Where is your JOIN ?. Can you provide your full SQL query ?.

Comment: No FROM clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `COALESCE`, something like this;

```
SELECT
    t1.name
    ,COALESCE(t1.email, t2.email,'-') email
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.callingcardid = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks, I was over complicating it. This is simple and works. Funny, just when I got it working, it turns out I don't even need the query, since client's software automatically updates the email to table1 if it exists on table2 :P

Answer (score 0):

This query takes into account the possibility that an email may be either `NULL` or empty string in the first table.  In both these cases, the email from the second table will then be used.  In case no email information be available, a single dash will be displayed for the email.

```
SELECT t1.name,
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(t1.email, '') = ''
            THEN COALESCE(t2.email, '-')
            ELSE t1.email END AS email
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.callingcardid = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   Table1.name 
       , CASE WHEN ISNULL(Table1.email,'') = '' 
              THEN Table2.email 
              ELSE Table1.email 
         END Email 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.name = Table2.name
```